How to prove $\displaystyle f(n,k;p)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\dfrac{(pz+1-p)^n}{z^{k+1}}\,\mathrm dz={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$?
How do you prove that
$$f(n,k;p)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\dfrac{(pz+1-p)^n}{z^{k+1}}\,\mathrm dz={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
if $n\in\mathbf Z^+$, $k=0,1,...,n$ and $0<p<1$?
$\mathbf{ATTEMPT/EDIT}:$
I actually found an alternative derivation when I finally corrected a mistake I made when taking the $k$th derivative.
$Derivation:$
In view that the integrand has the form
$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{(z-0)^{k+1}},\ f(z)\equiv (pz+1-p)^n$$
with $f(z)$ analytic inside and on the contour, we can make use of the $k$th derivative Cauchy's integral formula to get
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\dfrac{(pz+1-p)^n}{z^{k+1}}\,\mathrm dz&=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dz^k}\left[(pz+1-p)^n\right]_{z=0}\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}n(n-1)...(n-k-1)p^k\left[(pz+1-p)^{n-k}\right]_{z=0}\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\
&={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
\end{aligned}$$

Just to be clear, do you want to show that $$f(n,k;p) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Yes, it should be it.

Define $g(z) = \frac{(pz+1-p)^n}{z^{k+1}}$. From Residue theorem, $f(n,k;p) = \text{Re}(g(z),0)$. Therefore, we require the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in Laurent expansion of $g(z)$ at $z=0$. We have $$ g(z) = \frac{1}{z^{k+1}}\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r}p^r z^r (1-p)^{n-r} = \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} p^r (1-p)^{n-r}z^{r-k-1}.$$
For $r=k$ we will obtain the required coefficient. Thus $$ \boxed{f(n,k;p) =\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}} $$

I'll upvote your answer for the efforts even though I finally could derive it myself (I found my mistake).
